# Icon is not shown in the taskbar

Tags: vb.net

On other forms, the icon is shown in the taskbar but only in this form, the icon is not shown in the taskbar.

I also made sure that there is an icon in the form's property. 
[image]

Comment: Try setting the Icon Property in Project Properties->Application Tab

Comment: How is the form shown? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right Click the **Project** file and Select **Property**  as follows

[image]

2. Now Change the default Icon here

[image]

Comment: I already made sure that my icon is right and every form has an icon. I tried this method: Load the form (icon not shown in taskbar) > click the back button > load the form again (icon is now shown in the taskbar). I guess it's because of the MATLAB's DLL that I'm calling. Because when I load the form, I'm also calling the DLL that I build in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the program from the exe in the debug/release folder.
I've found that the icon doesn't show in the taskbar when run from the debugger.

Edit: Just realised how old this is.

Well, hopefully this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

To change the main icon for your application, go to the "Application" tab under the project property page, and change the "Icon:" combo box.

You can change icon form from properties form like this picture.

[image: chang icon form taskbar]

Comment: I already made sure that my icon is right and every form has an icon. I tried this method: Load the form (icon not shown in taskbar) > click the back button > load the form again (icon is now shown in the taskbar). I guess it's because of the MATLAB's DLL that I'm calling. Because when I load the form, I'm also calling the DLL that I build in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change icon of application from Project Properties -> Application -> Icon

Comment: I already made sure that my icon is right and every form has an icon. I tried this method: Load the form (icon not shown in taskbar) > click the back button > load the form again (icon is now shown in the taskbar). I guess it's because of the MATLAB's DLL that I'm calling. Because when I load the form, I'm also calling the DLL that I build in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

In properties of the form, browse for an icon in the icon tab.

Make sure that the picture you are using is in .ICO format. Sometimes, in newer versions, the language accepts images other than .ICO format but can produce error and doesn't display correctly everywhere.

Make sure that the .ICO you have converted is in more than 1 or 2 sizes (.ICO files have many resolutions in just one file).

I hope you understand!

Comment: I already made sure that my icon is right and every form has an icon. I tried this method: Load the form (icon not shown in taskbar) > click the back button > load the form again (icon is now shown in the taskbar). I guess it's because of the MATLAB's DLL that I'm calling. Because when I load the form, I'm also calling the DLL that I build in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers here, make sure that the 'ShowInTaskbar' property on the form is set to true. Sometimes settings get toggled. Toggle it back.